# Pass back entity id to the client side after saving it in the db

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity, domain-driven-design

I have a post method in my mvc controller that saves (using ajax call) newly created task. Since task is a domain entity, while creating an entity I generate (on server side) unique id - GUID for it.

When task is successfully created I need to pass this GUID back to the client side to complete creation of new html element that will be shown on the page.

Of course I can return this GUID back from controller save method but I don't really like it since in my opinion it breaks SRP rule. Save task method should only be responsible for saving entity, not for returning value.

Another option is to perform one more ajax call after single task is saved, fetch all tasks with all needed info (including GUIDs) and render all of them once again on the page - not really good since I have all needed information on client side (except GUID) to create new task by using for instance jsrender.

Yet another option would be to create GUID on client side. As far as I know there are some scripts available that can do that. But I would prefer to create GUIDs on server side.

Is there any better approach available? Or I am trying to complicate things too much and I simply should return GUID value from save method?

Please let me know what do you think. Thanks!

Comment: Creating the GUID is a logical part of saving an entity, why would it break SRP ?

Comment: That is true, but what breaks SRP is returning this GUID from save controller method back to the client. I think that save method should be of void type. It should not return anything. Or?

Comment: Usually 'Add' (`Save`) method returns created entity on the server side. To the client side you can provide either serialised entity or its identifier. Otherwise it will be needed to add extra complexity into a simple behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Save shouldn't return new entity, but not because of SRP (it has nothing to do with it). Save is simply setting new ID to the AR that you passed to save method. Most (if not all) ORMs do it the same way.

```
foo = fooFactory() // aggregate root factory
print foo.id // None
fooRepository.save(foo)
print foo.id // newly created id
```

Now just return it to your ajax view.